# How to remove "Dash Plugins" from Applications lens?

Tags: unity-dash, lenses

[image]

See the picture above. In the Applications lens of the Dash, you have the "Installed" field, and the "Dash plugins" field. I never use this field at all, but by default it appears expanded, not the "Installed" field. How can I removed the "Dash plugins" field from the Applications lens entirely, so that it only shows the "Installed" apps?

(I already used Unity Tweak Tool to remove the "recent items" and "More suggestions", etc.)

(Asked while using Ubuntu 15.10 x64 with Unity 7.3.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using 16.04.

Open `/usr/share/unity/scopes/applications.scope`:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/unity/scopes/applications.scope
```

and remove this:

```
[Category scopes]
Name=Dash plugins
Icon=/usr/share/icons/unity-icon-theme/places/svg/group-installed.svg
DedupField=uri
SortField=scope_disabled;title;
ContentType=apps
RendererHint=toggled
```

Comment: You're awesome! That fixed it (currently using 16.04 as I write this). Thanks so much.

Comment: I think this is a permanent solution, it worked also on 17.04

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but a quicker way of removing scopes would be this command:

```
apt-get remove unity-scope-* unity-scope-home+
```

It removes all the ones that aren't required for Ubuntu, and leaves the one that is (tested with 16.04).

Answer (score 0):

You have to uninstall them one by one...

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run :

```
sudo apt-get purge unity-scope-audacious unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks unity-scope-clementine unity-scope-colourlovers unity-scope-devhelp unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks unity-scope-gdrive unity-scope-gmusicbrowser unity-scope-gourmet unity-scope-guayadeque unity-scope-manpages unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-musique unity-scope-openclipart unity-scope-texdoc unity-scope-tomboy unity-scope-video-remote unity-scope-virtualbox unity-scope-yelp unity-scope-zotero unity-lens-music unity-lens-photos unity-lens-video unity-scope-calculator
```

Comment: would the dash still search my applications and files with all scopes uninstalled?

Comment: And performing this command does remove some of the dash plugins from the applications lens, but not all. There's still one for Banshee, Rhythmbox, Facebook, etc.